# "Send List Email" visibility problem

Tags: email, list, visibility

When an email is sent via the "Send List Email" option, only the sender of the email can see the email associated with the Contact when they are looking at the Contact's Past Activity related list.

When a user sends an individual email via Salesforce to a Contact using the Email tab, all internal users can see the message associated with the Contact when looking at the Contact's Past Activity related list.

I feel like this is a right's issue, but I don't know what object to change the rights on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by creating a sharing rule to override the default private OWD on the List Email option.